# Double negative in sentence "一人くらいは来てくれるんじゃないかな..."

Tags: grammar, meaning, syntax

I was wondering about the translation of this sentence:
(一人くらいは来てくれるんじゃないかな...)
What I see is a double negative and a question.
Does someone know if the double negative and question are used to *save face*, in a sense, from the speaker, or am I missing something really obvious...

来てくれるん - first negative.
じゃない - second negative.

Comment: Maybe it'll help if you explained where the first and second negatives are.

Comment: There *is* a ん that makes a verb negative, but it's in the same place as ない; in other words, if this were the ～ん negative, it would be 来てくれん. (Other examples: 飲まん, 食べん, 分からん.)

Comment: 来てくれるん is contraction of 来てくれるの and it's not negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In** **general** I think it's correct to say double negative and question are used to save face but I'm not sure if this sentence is double negative.

The expression 来てくれるん is not a negative sentence and also the expression `～じゃない？` does use the negative form but is not really a negative sentence either and is more like a question.

For example, something similar in English may be

> Isn't it cold?

Japanese translation would be

> 寒｛さむ｝くない？

The expression `～んじゃない？` is used to say something with some assumptions and also kind of asking for agreement from the listener just like the example above.

Some examples are:

> 今日は雨がふるんじゃない？

(You see dark clouds) Don't you think it's going to rain?

> A:　あ！財布｛さいふ｝がない！
>
> B:　レストランに　忘れたんじゃない？

(You saw your friend use her/his wallet at the restaurant) Maybe you left it at the restaurant?

`～かな...` is used to make it not sound like pushy when stating your opinion. I think it's because it sounds like you are stating your opinion as if you are asking it to yourself or talking to yourself. It's like `hmm I think`.

Comment: I know that じゃない is used as a question but the sentence already ends with a かな, and doesn't the ん after 来てくれる make it a negative verb?

Comment: I've edited my answer and added some examples. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

"来てくれるんじゃないか" is same with "来てくれるのではないか", hence it is not negative.

"ではないか(な)" such as "来るのではないか" is thinking/guessing/suspecting a possibility. The sentence means that the talker thinks (or expects) there is a possibility that at least one may come. I believe face(shame or pride) is not related here.