# What the function of expressions in bold?

Tags: grammar

Could you please check the 4th and the 5th sentence if I wrote it right. Especially parts in bold.

Below you can see my translation. Of course, it is not perfect, but I hope it will provide you some context.

1. 母: -お食事の用意ができましたよ。- (Your) food is prepared.
2. 田中: -どこの部屋。- In which room it is in?
3. 母: -お座敷に用意したけど。- In zashiki* room (a traditional Japanese-style room*)
4. 田中: -**どうかな**。もうお客あつかいは**やめた方がいいんじゃないかな**。山田さん、どう。- **I don't know.** Maybe you shouldn't stop inviting people (to launch). Mr. Yamada, what do you think?
5. 山田: -ええ、**そうしていただいた**方がいいです。- Yes, I would invite them too.

Comment: `～んじゃないかな` `shouldn't stop` -- This thread may help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38428/9831

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please review our page on how to ask questions, and if you are still unclear on any part of your question please edit it to meet the guidelines: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se

Comment: The source of your confusion is お客扱い and んじゃないかな. Please note that we don't handle "just check/translate this please" type questions. Please always try to explain WHY your translation did not work. (I know it's somewhat self-evident in this case, but a rule is a rule...)

Answer (score 0):

1. [Mother] (Yamada's) dinner is ready.  (Yamada is a house guest and it's been some time, like a week)
2. [Tanaka] Which room? (in the house)
3. [Mother] Well, figured Zashiki (Japanese style guest room, not to stay but to greet/dine) would be good?
4. [Tanaka] Hmm, not sure about that, isn't it high time Yamada's part of the fam? What do you say Yamada? (suggesting s/he eat at dining room or kitchen with the family) (literal translation; we should stop treating him/her like a guest. But IMO it could sound either positive or negative when spelt so in English)
5. [Yamada] Indeed, I'd like that.

Comment: Could you please try to avoid answering off-topic questions? Please at least wait for the OP to edit their question to meet our guidelines. Thank you.

Comment: well, sorry, didn't mean to offend but how's this "off topic"? This is a Japanese language board and it's not OK to ask where someone's stuck understainding it? To me it sounds like absolutely correct topic.

Comment: このサイトでは、訳してください(translation request)とか、翻訳があってるか見てください（proofreading request)という質問は、オフトピックという方針になっておりまして。こちらをご覧ください：https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/9831

Comment: @JunSato The question failed to meet the standards in a couple of ways. 1) It didn't show any research effort. Looking up the meaning of ほうがいい for example is something they could have easily done before posting. There was no evidence that the OP had tried to understand the bolded parts. 2) There were multiple grammar points which should have been addressed in separate questions. I think the preferred option (only my personal opinion) would have been to add a comment asking the OP to improve the question before providing an answer. ...

Comment: ... you shouldn't feel sorry for trying to help someone, but at the same time we need to discourage poor quality questions. Sometimes it's a tricky balancing act and difficult to decide where to draw the line.